# Z3 model for a table

Tags: z3, solver

I am trying to get my head around Z3. Tthough I understand the basic principles and the examples for solving basic problems.

I am creating a symbolic dynamic execution tool and use Z3 as solver. In the sample program under test there's is a condition `table.Rows.Count == 1`, which I have successfully manually translated into a Z3 model with a solution:

```
(declare-datatypes () ((Type (Char) (Decimal) (String) (Bool) (Int))))
(declare-datatypes (T S) ((Column (mkcol (first T) (second S)))))
(declare-datatypes () ((Row (Array (String (Column Type String))))))
(declare-datatypes () ((Table (Array (Int (Row))))))
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const row Row)
(declare-const column (Column String String))
(declare-const c Row)
(declare-const x Int)
(declare-const table Table)
(declare-const table.Rows (List Row))
(declare-const list2 (List Row))
(assert (not (= table.Rows nil))) ; an actual instance (not null)
(assert (= (head table.Rows) row)) ; firt row

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

And the solution

```
sat 
(model 
  (define-fun table.Rows () (List Row) 
    (insert (Array (mkcol String "")) nil)) 
  (define-fun row () Row 
    (Array (mkcol String ""))) 
)
```

I don't think my input model is perfect and then I don't know how to model the constraint `(int)table.Rows[0]["name"]`, i.e. the named cell contains a `int` value.

So my question is how to model this and how to approach such translations from these more complicated code constraints written in code to Z3 constraints (i.e. type mapping). And answering basic questions like

- Should the `Rows` property be modeled as `(declare-const table.Rows (List Row))` on the `table` variable?
- Or the `Rows` property should be modeled using custom sort?
- Should `Count` be also declared or it can be "by-passed" by multiple `head` and `tail` assertions?

If you can recommend any paper or post or project, that would be awesome :)

Thanks,

Karel

Comment: This is such a wide-ranging question, I'm afraid it isn't really suitable for StackOverflow. Without looking into the details, it's impossible to opine what the best strategy would be. Most likely you'll have to experiment and choose between clarity, ease of modification, and decidability. But one thing is for sure: If you can at all avoid SMTLib as you experiment, that would serve you well. Can you use one of the higher level APIs? Python is easiest to use, but there are bindings to many languages; including dotnet variants, C/C++/Java and even Scala and Haskell.

Comment: Thanks for comment, at this point I would like a push in the right direction. My strategy is automation and decidability. Also thanks for recommending the Python API, it is much easier to use.

Comment: Feel free to ask again when you have more specific questions. These modeling questions are important for the community, but they need to be more specific to be suitable for StackOverflow. Good luck!

Comment: I have found this project with Python Z3 extensions for OOP https://github.com/STAMP-project/ozepy. Still, though, having problems with understanding sets in Z3.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the project I was able to come up with a solution

```
from model import *
from z3 import *

import yaml
import pprint
import inspect
import linecache
import timeit
import itertools

classes_yaml = """
-
  name: DataColumn
  attribute: [{name: Value, type: Integer}]
- 
  name: DataTable
  reference: [
    {name: Rows, type: DataRowCollection}
  ]
-
  name: DataRow
  reference: [
    {name: Columns, type: DataColumn, multiple: true}
  ]
-
  name: DataRowCollection
  reference: [
    {name: Row, type: DataRow, multiple: true}
  ]
"""

classes = yaml.load(classes_yaml)
DataColumn, DataTable, DataRow, DataRowCollection = load_all_classes(classes)

dc = DefineObject('col1', DataColumn)

drc = DefineObject('drc', DataRowCollection)
dt = DefineObject('dt', DataTable).force_value('Rows', drc)
dr1 = DefineObject('dr1', DataRow)
dr2 = DefineObject('dr2', DataRow)
dr3 = DefineObject('dr3', DataRow)

generate_meta_constraints()
generate_config_constraints()

solver = Optimize()
solver = Solver()
solver.add(*get_all_meta_facts())
solver.add(*get_all_config_facts())

solver.add(dt.isinstance(DataTable))
solver.add(dt['Rows'] == drc)
solver.add(drc['Row'].count() == 1)
solver.add(dc['Value'] > 5);
solver.add(dr1['Columns'].count() == 1)

print(solver)
print(solver.check())
print(cast_all_objects(solver.model()))
```

The problem the solver is solving is to find a `DataTable` with a single `DataRow` that has a value greater than 5 in column with the name `Value`.

The resulting model is

```
{
   "dt":{
      "name": "dt", "type": "DataTable", "alive": True,
      "Rows": "drc"
   },
   "dr1":{
      "name": "dr1", "type": "DataRow", "alive": True,
      "Columns":[
         "col1"
      ]
   },
   "col1": {
      "name": "col1", "type":"DataColumn", "alive": True,
      "Value":6
   },
   "dr3": {
      "name": "dr3", "type": "DataRow", "alive": True, 
      "Columns": []
   },
   "dr2": {
      "name": "dr2", "type": "DataRow", "alive": True, 
      "Columns": []
   },
   "drc": {
      "name": "drc", "type": "DataRowCollection", "alive": True,
      "Row": [
         "dr2"
      ]
   }
}
```

This is not a generic solution and the assumptions class have to be recreated every time the code constraint is different, i.e. the assumptions and initilizations will be different for "2 rows with two distinct values table" problem. Also, the class definitions for `DataRow` will be different as well (but there might be a trick how to generalize it a little bit).